# Разрешат ли размещать мобильное приложение в google play и app store

Tags: appstore

Добрый день!

Есть фирма, которая делает специализированные сайты для узкой тематики. Изначально сайт шаблонный, покупатели потом доделывают дизайн, дописывают возможности и всячески с ним работают. Но техническая база у них одна.

Хочется сделать мобильное приложение, которое даст возможность получать данные некоторые с сайта и менять на нем некоторые настройки.

Перед разработкой приложения хотелось бы узнать, какие шансы, что это приложение получится разместить? Оно абсолютно бесполезно тем, у кого нет определенного сайта. И >99.9% посетителей в покупке не заинтересованы - тематика, повторюсь, очень узкая и специфическая.

При запуске приложения будет только три поля - адрес сайта, имя пользователя и пароль. Кнопки регистрации не будет, для использования приложения сперва нужно купить сайт.

У кого есть опыт размещения приложения - какие шансы размещения такого приложения у apple и android?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что в вашем случае ограничений на публикацию быть не должно.  Приложения узкой направленности есть в сторах. Отказ в публикации может возникнуть только по нескольким причинам, которые устанавливает стор, но в вашем случае нечего подобного не будет. С причинами отказа ты так же можете ознакомиться в справочной информации AppStore или Play маркет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!